# Formatting Tabular mysql results in mail on unix

Tags: mysql

I am trying to email mysql query results through mail command in unix as below.

```
mysql -uroot -p*** -e "select query" --table|mail -s "test" abc@example.com
```

but format is little bit creepy kind of below.

+--------------+-------------+
| PARTNER_NAME | ORDER_COUNT |
+--------------+-------------+
| Legacy       |           0 |
| NextJump     |           0 |
| Provide      |           0 |
+--------------+-------------+

Can you help me with formatting the output if you have any idea

Answer (score 1):

The formatting is down to the client in which you are reading the result. If the client is set to fixed width font then the display formatting will be as you expect.

Comment: I am using microsoft outlook ..so any idea to format the same in outlook?

Comment: Manually change to a fixed-width font.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to directly pipe it to mail you can

**A)** use the `-B` flag. The help is a bit confusing by saying:

> -B, --batch         Don't use history file. Disable interactive behavior.

but what it produces is this:

```
[root@server ~]# mysql -B -e 'select * from cities limit 2' test
id     name state_id
5562        20
5563   asd  20
```

**B)** format to html:

```
[root@server ~]# mysql -e 'select * from cities limit 2' test| sed -e 's/\|//g' | awk '{a++; if(a<2){print "<tr><th>" $1 "</th><th>" $2 "</th></tr>";} else { print "<tr><td>" $1 "</td><td>" $2 "</td></tr>"; }}'
<tr><th>id</th><th>name</th></tr>
<tr><td>5562</td><td>20</td></tr>
<tr><td>5563</td><td>asd</td></tr>
```

You still need to wrap this into `<table> ... </table>` and make sure your mail is sent as proper html otherwise it will be only be creepier.

As it was described by Baron Schwartz: https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/04/13/using-awk-to-convert-mysql-output-to-tables/